# Recreating java HashMap function in PHP

Tags: java, php, hashmap

```
<%
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Enumeration<String> paramsEnum = request.getParameterNames();
    while (paramsEnum.hasMoreElements()){
        String paramName = paramsEnum.nextElement();
        String paramValue = request.getParameter(paramName);
        params.put(paramName, paramValue);
    }


            Iterator<Map.Entry<String,String>> paramsIterator = params.entrySet().iterator();
            while (paramsIterator.hasNext()){
                Map.Entry<String,String> param = paramsIterator.next();
    %>
        <div>
            <span><%=param.getKey() %>:</span><span><%=param.getValue() %></span>
        </div>
        <%} %>
    <%
    paramsIterator = params.entrySet().iterator();

    while (paramsIterator.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry<String,String> param = paramsIterator.next();
        out.print("<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"" + param.getKey() +"\" name=\""+ param.getKey() +"\" value=\""+param.getValue()+"\"/>\n");
    }
    //Sign the signed fields and passed off as signature
    //Signature is mandatory
    out.print("<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"signature\" name=\"signature\" value=\""+Signature.sign(params)+"\"/>\n");
```

Sample generated value for signature input :

```
cFVmESCyYstDGqf2IKetxf1uYvLCgc9ill8yLthSJt0=
```

From the code above I can roughly understand that, the above code generated base64 like signature string for the input tag at the bottom, I wanna recreate the function in PHP and I have no clue about it since I have no experience in Java before.

I wanna do is to create a function which can generate a random string/hash as given sample,Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I guess your question is bit incomplete. Do you want to implement a HashMap like collection on your own in PHP?

Comment: Forgive my java but I believe a `HashMap` is just an unordered collection of keys and values - so you could just use an associative array (which is not unordered but anyway) or you could create your own object implementing the [`Iterator` interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php)?

Comment: Just reading here - `HashMap` allows `null` keys and `null` values - obviously PHP arrays don't technically allow `null` keys - but maybe that's not important to your use case. It could help us if you clarify if there's specific functionality that `HashMap` provides which you are trying to recreate?

Comment: robot_alien,i have edited my question,hope now its more explicit.thanks.

Comment: Darragh Enright, i couldn't think of any,yes php arrays cast null to the empty.as long as i can create a function which generates a key as in sample above,job done.thanks